# Error on MySql Post "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm trying to make some simple node.js with Express requests to a todoList (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE), the GET function is working, but the POST is not, I constantly get the error:

`"ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"`

This is my Router

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const router = Router();
const taskController = require("../controllers/taskController");

router.get("/tasks", taskController.search);

router.post("/tasks", taskController.create);

router.put("/tasks/:id", taskController.update);

router.delete("/tasks/:id", taskController.delete);

module.exports = router;
```

This is my controller until the create function

```
const taskModel = require("../models/taskModel")

class TaskController {
    search(req, response) {
        console.log(taskModel)
        const taskList = taskModel.list()
        return taskList
            .then((list) => response.status(200).json(list))
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
                response.status(400).json(error.message)
            })
    }

    create(req, response) {
        const newTask = req.body
        const task = taskModel.create(newTask)
        return task
            .then((createdTask) =>
            response.status(201).json(createdTask)
            )
            .catch((error) => response.status(400).json(error.message))
    }
```

And this is my class Model

```
const connection = require("../infra/connection");
const cfg = require("../config/default.json");

class TaskModel {
  execQuery(sql, params = '') {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      connection.query(sql, params, (error, response) => {
        if (error) {
          return reject(error);
        }
        return resolve(response);
      });
    });
  }

  list() {
    console.log(cfg)
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM todolist.tasks";
    return this.execQuery(sql);
  }

  create(newTask) {
    const sql = "INSERT INTO todolist.tasks SET ?";
    return this.execQuery(sql, newTask);
  }
```

Initially I thought that the problem was related to some grammatical error.. I'm not sure that that's the case.

I need the POST command to work and I'm a little lost.

Answer (score 0):

You're using ? as a placeholder for the entire object (newTask) in the INSERT INTO statement. MySQL doesn't support this syntax.

1. Prepared Statements (Recommended for Security):

This approach avoids SQL injection vulnerabilities.
Modify TaskModel.create to use prepared statements with named placeholders:

```
create(newTask) {
  const sql = `INSERT INTO todolist.tasks SET 
              title = ?, 
              description = ?,
              completed = ?`;
  const params = [newTask.title, newTask.description, newTask.completed]; 
  return this.execQuery(sql, params);
}
```

2. Object Destructuring (Simpler, but less secure):

Extract properties from newTask before building the query:

```
create(newTask) {
  const { title, description, completed } = newTask;
  const sql = `INSERT INTO todolist.tasks SET 
              title = '${title}', 
              description = '${description}', 
              completed = ${completed}`;
  return this.execQuery(sql);
}
```

Comment: You're right, MySQL doesn't support `?` as a placeholder for multiple assignments, but the use of the `?` placeholder is overloaded by the Node.js MySQL package. It actually does some query manipulation before the prepare. MySQL sees the proper syntax, but in Node.js you can pass a Javascript object and it expands it into a set of `key = ?` assignments automatically. See example here: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql?tab=readme-ov-file#escaping-query-values

Comment: And you would get a different error message if this insert statement were the cause of the issue.